# verifying checksum for an application

Tags: macos

I have downloaded one application and i have a *SHA-1 digest* for the same, how to check the authenticity of the download using **Terminal** on mac?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shasum` ([manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/shasum.1.html)):

```
$ shasum /path/to/file
```

and then check the output with the expected SHA-1 hash value.

Comment: the mac has `shasum`

Comment: @Petesh Cheers; didn't notice the typo.